# From stored procedure to excel via webpage, how?

Tags: .net, excel, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

We have a stored procedure that fetches all sales data from my company.

We have a web-system developed in .net

Now we want the customer to be able to download sales reports on our webpage.

How can we make the stored procedure results automatically into excel files available on our webpage?

Extra question: We also need to insert formulas to the excel sheet, in which stage is this best to do? And how?

All ideas/guides etc would be nice :)

Comment: Try getting the data in your web page, format it as an HTML table and then add code to export to Excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lebowski!

I wanted to possibly suggest a different way of approaching this.  I recently went through this same thought process of providing a client with an excel sheet that would need be generated monthly, quarterly, etc. through our website; but the excel sheet also needed formulas, which I couldn't find an answer as to how we could implement that.

What we did instead was first crafted the excel sheet (formulas and all).  Instead of a stored procedure, we created a view to grab all the relevant data.  Then, from Excel, we connect to the database (in this scenario you would need your db server accessible to the client).  See [this article](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/connect-to-import-sql-server-data-HA010217956.aspx) for details on connecting to the DB from the Excel sheet.

After that, we used a pivot, and pulled data directly from the pivot to the main sheet.  Then, we used that data where we needed formulas.

We created SQL credentials that only had access to the view(s) we made, and distributed the spreadsheet to the clients.  Now, they just click "Refresh All" on their spreadsheet, enter the credentials we gave them, and their spreadsheet pulls the most recent data.

I hope this alternative approach is helpful to you.  It certainly was to me.

Comment: Thank you for that great idea! I will surely have it in mind. Did you use any kind of guides or something that could help me on the way?

Comment: @Lebowski - I wish I had guides to use!  But the gist of it is to use a view instead of a stored procedure.  Create a new user with access only to that view.  Pull the information onto the excel sheet (maybe on a hidden sheet), and make a pivot from it.  You can pull field information from pivots with `getpivotdata()`, in excel, to use your formulas.  If you ever end up with null values in the pivot, use the format like this:  `=IF(ISERROR(GETPIVOTDATA([pivot info]),0,GETPIVOTDATA([pivot info])`  It will change a null to a 0.  That was the biggest headache for me.